# how to print jasper report without preview in java

Tags: java, printing, jasper-reports

I'm generating receipt using *JasperReports* but i want to print it automatically or just program the attributes without previewing its output. What could be the possible codes.

```
try {
    String get1 = lblORNum.getText();
    String get2 = lblInfoID.getText();
    JasperDesign jd = JRXmlLoader.load("directory");
    String sql = "select * from student, transaction, cashier where transaction.orNum=" + get1 + " AND student.id='" + get2 + "'";
    JRDesignQuery query = new JRDesignQuery();
    query.setText(sql);
    jd.setQuery(query);
    JasperReport jr = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jd);
    JasperPrint jp = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jr, null, conn);
    JasperViewer.viewReport(jp, false);
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure about what are your intentions, but if you're just saying that you don't want the Jasper Viewer (the window that opens the report as a preview after it's generation) you have only to remove the line: `JasperViewer.viewReport(jp, false);`

Comment: the viewer to false thing, I'd got that how can i print it directly without a print dialog. I just wanna print it automatically after clicking a button.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JRPrintServiceExporter to print a JasperPrint report.

See demo/samples/printservice in the JasperReports distribution package for an example.

Answer (score 0):

From

```
JasperViewer.viewReport(jp, false);
```

You can get a preview.
From

```
JasperPrintManager.printReport(jp,false);
```

You can directly print your report.
If you don't want a preview use only second code.